# How to connect to mysql database (RDS instance under AWS) from

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I created RDS instance for mysql database in AWS console.
I managed to connect to in my laravel 8 app with parameters in .env file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tads
DB_USERNAME=app_admin_name
DB_PASSWORD=app_admin_password
```

I tried to connect to this database from MySQL Workbench.
Creating RDS instance I set parameter
Public Access set “Yes” for security - I suppose I can to connect to MySQL Workbench with it.

In MySQL Workbench on tab “Under Remote Managent” :

- In hostname field I entered : myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com  In
  usernmne field I entered : app_admin_name In password field I entered
  : app_admin_password In SSH Key Path field I selected : path to pem
  file I use for access my aws instance in the console

But I got error:
ERROR [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.ssh/config'

In the console of my ubuntu I run :

```
sudo chmod  777  /home/user/.ssh/config
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

But I got next error :

```
SSH Connection Failed.
Check you SSH Connection settings and whether the SSH server is up.
Error : timed out
```

What is wrong and how can it be fixed?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
In MySQL Workbench I disabled “Remote Management” tab, where I tried to connect with ssh and

and on “Connection” tab I selected

```
Connection Method :“Standart(TCP/IP)” In hostname field I entered :
    myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com  In port field I entered : 3306 In
    usernmne field I entered : app_admin_name In password field I
    entered : app_admin_password
```

and in console Under Security Groups I added new group with Inbound rule : https://prnt.sc/1hxsfhq

But in MySQL Workbench I got error :

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 
with user tads_admin
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to connect to an Amazon RDS database via SSH? That is not supported. If you are wanting to connect from your own computer to an Amazon RDS database, set `Publicly Accessible=Yes`, add an an Inbound rule in the Security Group to permit your IP address access on port 3306 and connect normally.

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Database is launched in a **Public Subnet** (Defined as having a Route Table entry pointing to an Internet Gateway)
- Database configured as `Public Access = Yes`
- **Security Group** permitting Inbound access on port 3306 from your IP address
- Connect to the database via its **Endpoint Name**

This should be sufficient to have network access to the database.

If your attempt to connect takes a few seconds before failing, then it is an indication of a Networking problem. If all the above requirements are correct, then **try again from a different network** (eg office vs home vs tethered via your phone). Please note that your IP address will change for each of these connections.

You could also *temporarily* configure the Security Group to allow access from `0.0.0.0/0`, just to be sure that the IP address is not causing the problem.

Comment: Seems I made in a similar way 
but what is DNS Name you mentioned?
Not myrdsinstance name I wrote ?

under my instance I have several parameters, like 
Public IPv4 address
Private IPv4 addresses
Public IPv4 DNS
Elastic IP addresses
Private IPv4 DNS
VPC ID


Yes, trying to connect pause my Workbench in 15-20 seconds...

Comment: Sorry -- the wording in the console is **Endpoint name**. Did you try connecting from different networks? Did you try temporarily using `0.0.0.0/0` in the security group? Did you confirm that it is in a **Public subnet**?

Comment: If to Hostname field set myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com
and in related Security Group set Source custom “0.0.0.0/0"(Is it waht you call Public subnet ?)
In Workbench I got error anyway :
Failed to Connect to MySQL at myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 with user tads_admin
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
With pause in 15-20 seconds...

All params I fill are in 1ts “Connection” tab

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the database is in a Public Subnet? Can you try from a different network (eg home vs office vs tethered via phone)? Otherwise, it is a mystery! If you are subscribed to AWS Support, you can ask them.

Comment: Could you, please, what  Public subnet is ?

Comment: A Public Subnet has direct access to the Internet. The Route Table on the subnet should have an entry that points `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to an **Internet Gateway**. Without this entry, there is no communication between the subnet and the Internet.